# The antiderivative of $\sum_{n\gt 0}\frac{x}{n(x+n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, digamma-function

I tried to calculate $\int\sum_{n\gt 0}\frac{x}{n(x+n)}\, \mathrm dx$:
$$\begin{align}\int\sum_{n\gt 0}\frac{x}{n(x+n)}&=\sum_{n\gt 0}\frac{1}{n}\int\left(1-\frac{n}{x+n}\right)\, \mathrm dx \\&=\sum_{n\gt 0}\left(\frac{1}{n}\int\mathrm dx -\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{x+n}\right)\\&\overset{x+n\to x}{=}\sum_{n\gt 0}\left(\frac{x}{n}-\ln (x+n)\right)+C.\end{align}$$
It seems however, that the 'result' fails to converge for any $x$ (whereas $\sum_{n\gt 0}\frac{x}{n(x+n)}$ converges everywhere except for negative integers). How could a correct antiderivative be obtained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose the constants of integration wisely:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t}{n(t+n)} \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t}{n(t+n)} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{t}{n} - \log(t+n) \right]_{t=0}^{t=x} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{x}{n} - \log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right) \right).
\end{align*}

So in general,

$$ \int \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(x+n)} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{x}{n} - \log\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right) \right) + C. $$

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fractions, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(x+n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}
$$ This series is well-known; see, for instance, the link:
$$
= - \gamma + \psi_0(1+x) = -\gamma + \Gamma'(1+x)/\Gamma(1+x)
$$Integration is now easy.
$$
\int -\gamma + \Gamma'(1+x)/\Gamma(1+x)\,dx = -\gamma x + \log|\Gamma(1+x)|+ C
$$

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function
- https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#E6

Comment: I haven't heard of the digamma function. Could the antiderivative be evaluated by a bit more elementary means, similar to what is done in my approach?

Comment: You need to justify the interchange of sum and integral, but yeah your answer seems fine. Of course, the final series is somewhat opaque.

Comment: $\Gamma$ has no zeroes so the absolute value in the last line is redundant.